# Resolving adjoined relative clause with head nouns

Tags: linguistic-typology

In languages with adjoined relative clause, How do you know which relative clause maps to which head noun for adjoined relative clause if there are 2 head nouns each with an adjoined relative clause?

Comment: Are you taking about two sequential integrated (defining) relative clauses, for example "I like those ties [you wear] [that your sister knits for you]?.

Comment: no, not sequential integrated. each relative clause is modifying a different head noun, one acting as subject and the other as object.

Comment: Can you provide an example in English?

Comment: the kid ate the cake who I saw that I wanted

Comment: 3013 error: Starred uncapitalized sentence

Comment: @jlawler What does that mean?

Comment: @jlawler English does not have this kind of clauses. The example is just in english for understanding

Comment: Thank you. Do any languages have them?

Comment: @jlawler Yes, some languages have them here --> https://wals.info/chapter/90   Diyari, I believe